# How to work-around the transition for display property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that transitions for the display property don't work, but I was wondering if there is a work around for this. I tried the visibility property but it doesn't seem to suit the task I am trying to achieve, or maybe I did it wrong. As you can see, I am displaying different text when you hover over the anchor tag by setting the `span` to `display: none;`. Animating the opacity won't be a good solution because the element being animated will still occupy the space it held. Is there maybe a workaround in Javascript or jQuery? Here is the code. I left out the `transition` property and its prefixes for brevity. The animation I want is for it to switch slowly between the two, i.e. One fades out, the other fades in. There doesn't have to be an overlap, but it doesn't matter if there is.

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar">
 <ul>
 <li><a id="menu1" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>&nbsp;Home</span><span class="show">&nbsp;Welcome Home</span></a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.show, a:hover span { 
display: none; 
}
a:hover .show { 
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: What do you want the animation to look like? There are many possibilities.

Comment: Echoing @Pointy's sentiments, what exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using jquery slide transitions when you hover over the anchor element. Check out http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

An example is

`$("#menu1").hover(function () { $("#menu1 span").slideToggle("slow"); }, function(){ $("#menu1 span").slideToggle("slow"); });`

Answer (score -1):

You can try that on hover the object floats and animate the opacity. Making it float wont make him occupy the space.

Cheers J